# Как прочитать ответ контроллера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, moq

Делаю тестирование в дебаге вижу, что приходит нужный ответ, но не понимаю, как прочитать его:

Код тестирования:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllArticler()// System.NotSupportedException
{
    var result = controller.GetAll();

    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ActionResult<List<Article>>>(result);
    //viewResult.Result.
}
```

Метод в контроллере:

```
[HttpGet("GetAll")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult<List<Article>> GetAll()
{
    var list = _context.Articles.Include(article => article.Comments).ToArray();

    return Ok(list);
}
```

result у меня получает нужный ответ, но не могу получить из него данные?
В дебаг написано, что надо result.Result.Value - и там будет нужный мне список. Но такой возможности vs не показывает, к чему мне надо привести классы или что сделать?

Comment: [Unit test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Тут не важно, Core или обычный фреймворк, в документации показаны примеры ассёртов и моков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Слушай, а добавление в бд же не работает в moq??

Comment: Нет конечно. При использовании моков всё происходит в памяти. Поэтому тесты отрабатывают очень быстро и их можно запускать много раз в день.

Comment: Моки/фейки используются при модульном (юнит) тестировании. Если нужно протестировать работу с реальной БД, то это уже интеграционное тестирование. Моки при этом не используются. Такие тесты запускаются намного реже, обычно на билд-сервере, перед выпуском приложения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Печально, а какие тесты производятся с реально бд? Если говорить про rest API приложения и не selenium для тестов

Comment: Почему печально-то? Без работы с реальной БД (файловой системой, сетью и т. п.) юнит-тесты отрабатывают молниеносно. А главное - код для работы с БД может быть ещё не готов, а мы уже можем тестировать другой код, который будет использовать его потом.

Comment: Но никто не запрещает обращаться к реальной БД. Выкидываем Moq, создаём реальный экземпляр DbContext и вперёд.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А как тогда создавать экземпляр класса DbContextOptions, с ссылкой бд?

Comment: Вот! Мы пришли к пониманию, зачем нужны фейки в модульных тестах. Чтобы не мучиться в них с созданием реальных БД/файлов и т. п.

Comment: Создавать так же как делаете это в основной программе. Только строку соединения нужно указывать, естественно, другую. Чтобы не испортить данные в рабочей БД.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А есть статьи на эту тему или доки какие нибудь?
То просто ничего нормального не нашел, а от молейших изменений все ломается. Например раньше у меня возвращал метод: ActionResult<List<Article>>, то сейчас возвращает только ActionResult, потому что иначе в тесте ошибка.

И как передавать эту строчку на бд в тестах?